# permanently set goal in maven project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

After I updated my **intelij IDEA** I have an issue every time I run Maven project:
**[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build.**
This line in **pom.xml build section** fixes it:

```
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
```

But how can I specify goal permanently so it runs automatically during build?
I use **apache-maven-3.5.2**

Comment: Where do you have error on command line or inside IDEA ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have it inside IDEA when I click the 'Run' button.